# Automatically shorten paths over a character count limit in bash

Tags: linux, windows, macos, path, onedrive

Windows and tools running on windows servers (eg. OneDrive) have a limit on path lengths.

I am looking for a command line tool in OSX/Linux/Unix to, within a directory, shorten all paths above a path length threshold, for example, by keeping the first 5 characters and the last 5 characters of each folder/file name in overly long paths, starting with the names of folders and files most distant from the root (ie. most nested).

ie

```
folder_very_very_long_name/folder_very_very_long_name/folder_very_very_long_name/file_very_very_long_name
```

could become

```
folder_very_very_long_name/folder_very_very_long_name/folde_name/file__name
```

I can already identify the troublesome paths using:

```
find . -name \* -type f | perl -ne 's/(.*)/print length($1), " $1\n"/e' | sort -nu
```

from:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2590442?tstart=0

Comment: What do you want to happen if `folder_very_very_long_name/folder_very_very_long_name/folde_name/file__name` already exists?

Answer (score 1):

```
lp="folder_very_very_long_name/folder_very_very_long_name/folder_very_very_long_name/file_very_very_long_name"

IFS='/' read -a components <<< "$lp"

combined_path=""

for comp in "${!components[@]}"
do
    if [ ${#components[$comp]} -gt 0 ]; then
        a=$(echo ${components[$comp]} | cut -c -5);
        b=$(echo ${components[$comp]} | tail -r -c 6);
        if [ $comp -eq 0 ]; then
            combined_path="$a...$b"
        else
            combined_path="$combined_path/$a...$b"
        fi
    fi
done
echo $combined_path
```

#### Example Output:

```
folde..._name/folde..._name/folde..._name/file_..._name
```

#### Explanation:

`IFS`is your delimiter; you read in `lp` and store each part of your splitted string in the array `components`.

Then you iterate over each element in your array, using the if statement to check whether the respective `comp` is empty, thus indicating a path beginning at root. Using `cut` you get the first 5 characters and using `tail` the last 5. You then append that to your overall path `combined_path`, concatenating `a` and `b` with `...` between the two. (That's just to make the shortening more visible and can easily be left out).

Hope this helps you getting closer to your desired solution.

Comment: This requires a hard-coded input filename (lp) and it would be great to expand this to a more general case (using find ./).